# iOS 7 - XCode 5 - Constraints

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, constraints

I am trying to learn iOS development, but I need portrait and landscape in my project. As I set it up, I notice that I am messing everything up. I may need a bit of help with this.

This is what I need in landscape:
[image: 1]

Here it is in landscape:
[image: 2]

You see, I've been trying out Auto Layout, but it's been a really bad experience. How do I make constraints on this?

I need it to fit in Portrait and Landscape, but as soon as I fit it with either of them, it messes up the other view.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to pin the top, left, and right edges of your webview to the superview. Then create a vertical space constraint between the toolbar and the webview.

Comment: Since I am new to this feature, I'm confused. How do I pin edges to the superview and create a vertical space constraint between the toolbar and the webview?

Comment: The short answer is control+drag between views or use the buttons in the bottom right of the storyboard.